# Does C# have anything like package in java

Tags: c#, java, package, project

I'm new in C# and I'm now coding with Visual Studio 2013.

I'm developing a project and it can be divided into several functions.

When I want to separate the code into different packages like what I did with Java, I find that Visual Studio only offer me to create a new project in the same solution.

So does C# have anything like package in java? So that I can place my source properly. Or the project itself is just like packages in java?

Thank you very much!

Comment: u meen .dll or asambly ?

Comment: yes it has namespaces.... when ever you add new project to solution, it has its own namespace just like package in java.

Answer (score 1):

No,
C# has namespaces. You can normally wrap objects (classes, enums, structs, etc) in namespaces

```
namespace Whatever
{
    public class ClassA{}
    public struct StructA{}
}
```

Then to instantiate a ClassA do the following...

```
Whatever.ClassA _classA = new Whatever.ClassA();
```

You can also at a "using" directive so you don't have use the namespace all the time in your code file....

```
using Whatever;

ClassA _classA = new ClassA();
```

Hope it helps,
Leo

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to separate some sort of code from other.
you can use **namespaces** for doing that.

please find below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx

Comment: and also folders=packages don't forget you can create your own hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx) state:

> The namespace keyword is used to declare a scope that contains a set of related objects. You can use a namespace to organize code elements and to create globally unique types.

Instead of package c# using namespace.

for java you use the jar file here dll.using the namespace you can access the dll's.

you can separate the class file using the folder also.you need to create the folder under the project.